# iOS Motion vs Android Sensor quaternion data

Tags: android, ios, sensors, motion

The goal is simple: using my device to control a 3d game object in my game (rotate).

In iOS device, I use `CMDeviceMotion` to do get this job done, the code is simple:

```
quaternionX = motion.attitude.quaternion.x;
quaternionY = motion.attitude.quaternion.y;
quaternionZ = motion.attitude.quaternion.z;
quaternionW = motion.attitude.quaternion.w;
```

and in my game I use the `quaternion` data above converting it into rotation data in my game and everything works fine.

---

In android, the code is :

```
if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
    float[] temporaryQuaternion = new float[4];
    SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(temporaryQuaternion, sensorEvent.values);
    quaternionX = temporaryQuaternion[0];
    quaternionY = temporaryQuaternion[1];
    quaternionZ = temporaryQuaternion[2];
    quaternionW = temporaryQuaternion[3];
}
```

But this time the result did not turn out right in my game when I tried to use the `quaternion` I get from `SensorManager` the way I did with from iOS device.

I need some advice on how to get the `quaternion` data from an Android device just like I do from an iOS device so that I can use them the same way in my game.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

---

Update:

The right case with an iOS device (device laying down on table)

output data (x,y,z,w):

```
0.0006159197655506432 -0.0028661845717579126 -0.00002693507121875882 0.9999957084655762
0.0006073189433664083 -0.0028192626778036356 -0.00004078780330019072 0.9999958872795105
0.0005894795176573098 -0.002804218325763941 -0.00004623963832273148 0.9999958872795105
0.0005597725394181907 -0.0028200845699757338 -0.00009185218368656933 0.9999958872795105
0.000527433876413852 -0.002837945008650422 -0.00010885162919294089 0.9999958872795105
0.0005262080230750144 -0.0028331447392702103 -0.0000935369316721335 0.9999958872795105
```

the wrong case with an Android device (same way laying down on table)

```
-0.001673000049777329 -0.008166000247001648 0.974636971950531 0.22363300621509552
-0.0017000000225380063 -0.00812199991196394 0.9747239947319031 0.22325499355793
-0.001610000035725534 -0.008205000311136246 0.9744099974632263 0.22461800277233124
-0.0016240000259131193 -0.008062999695539474 0.9743139743804932 0.22504200041294098
-0.001627999939955771 -0.007942999713122845 0.9744499921798706 0.22445599734783173
-0.0013859999598935246 -0.007899999618530273 0.9747129678726196 0.22331200540065765
-0.0011889999732375145 -0.007706999778747559 0.9745630025863647 0.22397400438785553
```

Comment: `But this time the result did not turn out right in my game when I tried to use the quaternion I get from SensorManager the way I did with from iOS device.` what exactly does this mean ?

Comment: I updated my question with some detail information you can refer to. The output data of quaternion is different when I placed the device in the same way.